# java - duplicate case label

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to move my Maven-Application from Eclipse Java EE Luna to IntelliJ Idea 14.0.3.

When i try to build the Project in my new Idea IDE i receive for this pice of code the following Error:

***Error: java: duplicate case label***

```
char c = '-';
int postChar = -1;

switch (c) {
case 'ü': c = 'u'; postChar = 'e';
    break;
case 'ö': c = 'o'; postChar = 'e';
    break;
case 'ä': c = 'a'; postChar = 'e';
    break;
}
```

What's wrong with this Code ?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it is a problem with the encoding setting. Try the following:

1. Go to *Setting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>) > Editor > File Encodings*. Make sure "Project Encoding" (at the top) is set to "UTF-8". You probably also want to set the "IDE Encoding" to UTF-8 as well.

   - You may also want to set this in *File/Application > Other Settings > Default Settings* so future new projects default to those settings.
2. At the bottom right of the status bar (lower right corner), make sure the file's encoding is UTF-8. If not, change it:

[image]

3. If the above does not solve the issue, go to *Setting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>) > Build Execution, Deployment > Compiler* and in the "Additional build process VM Options" add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`. Also make sure that "Use compiler" at the top is set to `javac`. If you need an alternative compiler, you may have to troubleshoot the problem with that compiler. I would at least try the `javac` compiler so you can definitively say its an issue with the alternative compiler.

   - As an alternative, you can set the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` system/environment variable so it declares `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` and then restart IntelliJ IDEA so it picks up the change. After that all `java` and `javac` commands will use the file encoding setting. See the SO post [Setting the default Java character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding/623036#623036) for more detail.
4. The above should work. If it does not, try replacing the char declarations with Unicode escape sequences as a troubleshooting step:

   ```
   switch (c)
   {
       case '\u00FC':
           c = 'u';
           postChar = 'e';
           break;
       case '\u00F6':
           c = 'o';
           postChar = 'e';
           break;
       case '\u00E4':
           c = 'a';
           postChar = 'e';
           break;
   }
   ```

Comment: p.s. Also, in your maven POM, make sure you in the `<properties>` section you have set `<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`